# DAX - average with multiple filter conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data like:

```
  Folder      Replied Complied
1 testing     1            1
2 /complete/  0            1
3 none        1            1
4 Incomplete  0            1
5 complete//  0            0
6 Incomplete  1            0
7 ABCcomplete 1            1
```

I like a measure to calculate the average of `Complied` (sum divided by count), only where `Folder` contains the string `complete` AND `Replied` is `0` (both conditions simultaneously).

Therefore rows 2, 4, 5  should be used in the count, resulting in 0.66... (1 + 1 + 0)/3

i've tried several things but the formula either results in an error, or returns the wrong result

i.e.

```
Measure = CALCULATE (
    Average( [Complied]),
    CONTAINSSTRING([Folder],"complete") && [replied] = 0 
    )
```

DAX is very confusing to me. Thanks in advance

edit:
I've seen examples like
`

```
 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE([col]), CONTAINSSTRING([Folder],"complete") , [replied] = 0)
```

note the `,` instead of `&&` but that doesn't work for some reason either. Neither does `AND(condition1, condition2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dax measure should be the one you are looking for:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Sheet1[Complied]),
            CONTAINSSTRING(Sheet1[Folder],"complete") && Sheet1[Replied]=0)
```

**So how is it working?**

1. `ContainString` to check about "complete", work like `VBA instr` function
2. `&&` in order to meet both condition
3. `Calculate(method, expression)` to filter all the value

**Scorecard**

[image]

You may first test with the following measure to check `if statement` is working in your case first:

```
IF(CONTAINSSTRING(Sheet1[Folder],"complete") && Sheet1[Replied]=0,"True","False")
```

Only three row is True here:

[image]

Comment: for some reason this returns `the expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression`

Comment: Hmm, can you show how you sample table look like in PowerBI? Because i have no issue to calculate the average. Just notice I am using the same measure as you haha

Comment: One thing, how come your measure doesnot have `tablename` for each col header? such as `Sheet1[Replied]` instead of `[Replied]`?

Comment: In the actual powerbi, i wrote the table name, I cut it out here to keep it brief, I gotta do more research into the measure / data and get back to you. Thanks for your suggested solution!

Comment: Sure, you can take a look on my edited answer, see you can past the first test or not :)

Comment: i couldn't figure out why it wasn't working, so I used the new DAX column checker you proposed as the filter in `CALCULATE()`. It's amateur, but I am an amateur! Thanks

Comment: Welcome, as long as you find it useful :)